# Pandas-Export to CSV as a string (not date format)

Tags: excel, pandas, string, dataframe, export-to-csv

Pandas DataFrames - how do I export list 'X' to a CSV so it appears as a string? The problem is when I open the CSV using Excel it appears in date format.

```
X=['1-4', '1-5', '2-3', '4-8']
```

ie. when list 'X' is exported to a CSV and opened with Excel it appears as a date:

[image]

I would like list 'X' to appear in Excel as is - that is, not converted it to date format.
Desired output for Excel is:

[image]

I have tried the following code - but it throws an error:

```
import pandas as pd

X=['1-4', '1-5', '2-3', '4-8']
Y=[1,4,3,5]

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X,Y)))

column_names=['A','B']
df.columns=[column_names]

df.A.to_string()

df.to_csv('yyy.csv', mode='a', header=True)
```

Thankyou

Comment: Are you sure this is a panda issue and not due to some excel configuration ? Try copying the raw csv to make sure

Comment: Unfortunately it is Excel problem, it thinks working with datetimes, so converting. The best open csv files in some text editor, not in excel

Comment: OK thanks for this - Excel issue it is.

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

worked fine with me...
maybe the excel or whatever program u use to open the file is casting it... try open it as text file...

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Even if Excel reads in date format, when you open in pandas it will come in original format (at least in my case). If someone only wants to save data in csv and work in pandas again, it should be fine.

I also tried doing the 2nd option here (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-excel-convert-text-to-number-date-format-csv-file/) which transform the data as text. And then saving again. It worked for me.